# Recurrence relation inhomogeneous relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

$a_n = 4a_{n-1} - 4a_{n-2} + (n^2 + 1)2^n$

a) Find the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation.

b) Find the solution of the non-homogeneous relation, $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$

My work:

part (a):

$a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} = (n^2 + 1)2^n$

$a_n - 4a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} = 0$

$n^2 - 4n + 4 = 0$

$(n - 2)^2 = 0$

$n = 2$

So, $a_n = A(2)^n + B(2)^nn$

Is my part (a) correct?

part (b):

The reasonable result of the particular solution will be $(An^2 + Bn + C)2^n$

But and then, I don't know how to continue even I have substituted the result into the equation.

Comment: solve the homogeneous equation and then try to find a special solution of the inhomogeneous one

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of the homogenous recursion is $x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2$ hence each sequence $a_n=p(n)2^n$ for some polynomial of degree $d$ is such that $a_n-4a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}=q(n)2^n$ for some polynomial $q$ of degree $d-2$. To get $q(n)=n^2+1$, try $p(n)$ of degree $4$ with no term $n^1$ or $n^0$ since these would vanish. In other words, compute $q(n)=p(n)-2p(n-1)+p(n-2)$ for $p(n)=n^2$ (answer $2$), for $p(n)=n^3$ (answer $6n+b$) and for $p(n)=n^4$ (answer $12n^2+cn+d$) and deduce $p(n)=An^4+Bn^3+Cn^2$ solving $p(n)-2p(n-1)+p(n-2)=n^2+1$, then a particular solution is $a_n=p(n)2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting your solution into the homogeneous equation one gets:
\begin{align}
0 
&= A 2^n + B n 2^n - 4(A 2^{n-1} + B (n-1) 2^{n-1}) + 4 (A 2^{n-2} + B (n-2) 2^{n-2} \\
&=A 2^n + B n 2^n - 2A 2^n- 2 B(n-1) 2^n + A 2^n + B(n-2) 2^n \\
&= (A + n B - 2A - 2 B(n-1) + A + B(n-2)) 2^n \\
&= 0 \cdot 2^n \\
&= 0
\end{align}
So your a) part looks fine.

Regarding b):

The general solution will be
$$
a_n = (A + B n) 2^n + b_n
$$
where $b_n$ is some particular solution.
The conditions require
$$
0 = a_0 = A + b_0 \\
1 = a_1 = 2(A+B) + b_1
$$
so the asked for solution is
$$
a_n = (-b_0 + ( (1-b_1)/2+b_0) n) 2^n + b_n
$$
This leaves the problem of finding one particular solution $b_n$. Any will do. Assuming
$$
b_n = p(n) 2^n
$$
for some order $N$ polynomial $p$ seems to be a possible way.
I end up with a fourth order polynomial after some lengthy calculation.

Comment: But how about the part B?? I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Solving the recurrence using Mathematica's RSolve gives an answer for which $a_n$ is indeed of the form $p(n)2^n$ with $p(n)$ a fourth-order polynomial. (You say it for $b_n$, but of course the same is true for $a_n$.) So it doesn't seem pleasant no matter how you slice it...

Comment: I also tried removing the inhomogenity by subtracting $b_{n+1} - b_{n}$. Then apply the process again. (Is this symbolic differentiation?) I end up with a homogeneous equation with characteristic polynomial  $p(t) = t^5 - 5 t^4 + 10 t^3 - 10 t^2 + 10 t - 6$ or such. This features one real and four complex roots. Not sure if that would yiield a simple solution in the end.

Comment: So the result I guessed is wrong? $a_n = (An^2 + Bn + C)2^n$ ?

Comment: "I end up with a fourth order polynomial after some lengthy calculation." For short, methodical, computations and the reason why degree 4 is necessary and sufficient, see my comment on main.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write the recurrence shifted, multiply by $zn^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize parts of the result:

$\begin{align*}
   a_{n + 2}
     &= 4 a_{n + 1} - 4 A_n + ((n + 2)^2 - 1) \cdot 2^{n + 2} \\
   \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
     &= 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n - 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
         + \sum_{n \ge 0} (n^2 + 4 n) \cdot 2^n z^n \\
   \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
     &= 4 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
          - 4 A(z)
          + \sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 \cdot 2^n z^n
          + 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} n \cdot 2^n z^n
\end{align*}$

To dispatch the last two sums, start with:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{1}{1 - a z}
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a^n z^n \\
  \sum_{n \ge 0} n a^n z^n
     &= z \frac{d}{d z} \sum_{n \ge 0} a^n z^n \\
     &= z \frac{d}{d z} \frac{1}{1 - a z} \\
     &= \frac{a z}{(1 - a z)^2} \\
  \sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 a^n z^n
     &= z \frac{d}{d z} \frac{a z}{(1 - a z)^2} \\
     &= \frac{a z(1 + 1 z)}{(1 - a z)^3} 
\end{align*}$

Pulling all together, and solving for $A(z)$:

$\begin{align*}
  A(z)
    &= \frac{1}{2 (1 - 2 z)^5}
         - \frac{3}{4 (1 - 2 z)^4}
         - \frac{3}{4 (1 - 2 z)^3}
         + \frac{9}{4 (1 - 2 z)^2}
         - \frac{5}{4 (1 - 2 z)}
 \end{align*}$

Remembering:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 + u)^{-m}
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k \\
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
\end{align*}$

we get:

$\begin{align*}
   a_n
     &= [z^n] A(z) \\
     &= \frac{1}{2} \binom{k + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} \cdot 2^n
          - \frac{3}{4} \binom{k + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} \cdot 2^n
          - \frac{3}{4} \binom{k + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \cdot 2^n
          + \frac{9}{4} \binom{k + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} \cdot 2^n
          - \frac{5}{4} \binom{k + 1 - 1}{1 - 1} \cdot 2^n \\
    &= \frac{k^4 - 12 k^3 + 11 k^2 + 108 k - 60}{48} \cdot 2^n
\end{align*}$